# Why am I getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendkeys' error in Python 3.11.3 Selenium automation with Chrome 113.0.5672.127?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, pycharm

I am using selenium 4.9.1, Chrome Version 113.0.5672.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
python 3.11.3, I am trying to run a selenium function which uses `sendkeys()`:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL PC\PycharmProjects\salmanpythontest\new.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").sendkeys("abc@gmaail.com")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'
```

[code screen shot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRlmJ.png)

I am trying to login in a module

Comment: `find_element_by_id("email")` did not find any matching element, so it returned `None`.

Comment: Although this is odd; I thought in such a case, the function would raise a `NoSuchElement` exception, instead of returning None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element_by_id` - This method has been deprecated and removed from selenium `v4.3.0` and onwards.

Since you are using selenium `v4.9.1`, you should use this method `find_element` instead.

So, replace the below line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("email").sendkeys("abc@g.com")
```

To:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
```

You will need below import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you encountered, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'," indicates that you are trying to use the send_keys method from the Selenium library on a variable or object of type None.
This error typically occurs when the object you are trying to interact with using Selenium has not been found or initialised correctly.

Ensure that the "email" is the right locator id you are using.

I have visited the URL, seems like the id of the locator should be "testing" not "email".

[Look at the DOM here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C499U.png)